# WPF DataGrid Column Resizing

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, resize

I have two wpf datagrids having same number of columns. I want to resize the same column in second grid when user resize the column of first grid.

Thanks,
ant.

Comment: Take a look at this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414310/wpf-datagrid-sync-column-widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414310/wpf-datagrid-sync-column-widths)