# WPF DataGrids with same column width

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF Window with 2 DataGrids, each DataGrids has 6 DataGridTextColumn columns.

Only thing I like is once user OR system resize any column width on DataGrid #1, my app should set same column widths on DataGrid #2.

First I thought I bind each column "Width" property and that's all, but according to these:

[How to bind datagrid columns width in WPF (MVVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241116/how-to-bind-datagrid-columns-width-in-wpf-mvvm)

[Binding datagrid column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313586/binding-datagrid-column-width)

I was wrong.

I tried that Rachel mentioned "Alternatively, you can define your own DataGridCellTemplate with a control that has it's Width bound to whatever the property is on your DataItem"

but still no luck, column widths not updating at resizing.

Also, I tried with this:
http://dotnetgenetics.blogspot.hu/2016/04/wpf-datagridcell-resize-event.html

At least I can catch resize event, but no idea how I can figure out that which DataGrid and which column sent this event to resize another DataGrid.

I prefer a XAML-only solution if any.

Could you help me please?

It looks I found one solution:
[WPF DataGrid Sync Column Widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414310/wpf-datagrid-sync-column-widths?rq=1)

So my working solution is:

I handle LayoutUpdate event on both DataGrid, and I set new column widths like mentioned above by Ahmed Yasin Koçulu, but before I set new widths on DataGrid one, I unsubscribe LayouUpdate event on DataGrid two. When I finished setting new withd, I subcribe LayoutUpdate event again.

I'd still prefer a XAML-only solution if any

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF DataGrid Sync Column Widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414310/wpf-datagrid-sync-column-widths)

Comment: yes, I found my solution there

Comment: I just flagged your question as a duplicate of existing question you found - it will make existing solution link more noticable

Comment: Ok, thank you  . .